# what mongo files should not be tracked by git

Tags: git, mongodb

I've installed `MongoDB` in my `git` repository and configured `dbpath` to `./data/db`. (Basically inside `bin` folder)

It added (aside standard `.exe` files) files with extensions `.wt`, `.lock` and etc.

What files I can safely add to `gitignore`?

Comment: With some exceptions, generally speaking I ignore all database files from git and use separate backup strategies in order to maintain program-data independence. One example where you might want to commit would be some seed data for testing purposes. Other than that, just commit your schemas if you're using something like mongoose and ignore the whole `data/db` folder.

Comment: Well actually I do not have at all for mongo for now. I just want to create some configuration that can be used anywhere without additional files to pass.